# Jquery selecting element with nth:child returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a loop I am trying to get the id of an input element using jquery and the css `nth-child` selector..

JS code:

```
var questionid = "";
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            questionid = $('ul li:nth-child('+i+')input').attr("id");
            console.log(questionid);
        }
```

It returns:

```
 undefined
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and **[mcve]**.

Comment: Try `$('ul li:nth-child('+i+') :input').attr("id");`

Comment: @rayon doesnt work

Comment: @SangameshDavey, How does your HTML look like ? Will you mind sharing that as suggested in earlier comments ?

Comment: my html is generated (not manually)

Comment: function firstsubmit() {
    tablename = $("#tablename").val();
    depth = $("#depth").val();
    usertime = $("#usertime").val();
    questions = [];
    finalquestions = [];
    for(i=1;i<=depth;i++){
        questions[i-1] = "<li>"+tablename+"*"+i+"=<input type='number' id='res"+i+"'></li><span id='spanres"+i+"'></span>";
    }
    
    
    finalquestions = shuffleArray(questions);
    console.log(finalquestions);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    $(".questions ul").append(finalquestions[i]);
}
    
    
}

Comment: This piece of code generates the html

Comment: and the above code sent by me is working

Comment: @SangameshDavey If accepted answer is working, there us no way my comment will fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a descendent of `li` therefore you will need a space between your closing bracket of the nth-child selector and the word input.. https://jsfiddle.net/b9yov92h/

from:

```
 questionid = $('ul li:nth-child('+i+')input').attr("id");
```

to:

```
 questionid = $('ul li:nth-child('+i+') input').attr("id");
```